# Memory leaks in UITableView

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks

I am using custom cells to populate one of my table. but whenever I scroll up and down, I can see there are some leaks happening, which points to UIKit Lib. Not sure why? For the reference I have attached a screen shot of the leaks from the Leaks Instrument.

[image]

TableView cellForRowIndex:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"EditingCell_%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    EditingTableViewCell *cell = (EditingTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    
    if (!cell) {
        [self.appCellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];        
        cell = editingTableViewCell;        
        self.editingTableViewCell = nil;
    }
```

Custom Cell:

```
@implementation EditingTableViewCell

@synthesize label,textField,commentField,dateLabel;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark == Initialization == 

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark == Memory Management ==

- (void)dealloc {
    [label release];
    [textField release];
    [commentField release];
    [dateLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: the most interesting part must be in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: @Vince: I have cross checked it several times, but everything is fine out there.

Comment: Please put your tablecell creation code here

Comment: @manoj - so, I'm sorry, no idea why the leak is appearing

Comment: Please provide more detail of your code of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath here. So, can help you more.

Comment: @Joris,AppAspect: Edited my post as per request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is enough info to give a precise solution. However, my guess is that the properties are not well defined to be used in inflated xibs. For example you may have defined the property **label** as:

```
// Interface declaration
IBOutlet UILabel *label;

// property 

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
```

This is wrong and will cause leaks. The correct way for defining outlets is:

```
// Interface declaration
UILabel *label;

// property 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

This makes it so that when the xib is inflated the setting of the variables goes through the synthesized setters thus the memory management works as you would expect.

Hope it helps! Cheers

Comment: That's not an issue, I always prefer to declare properties like the 2nd one.